# TFS visual studio test "Test Filter criteria" and xunit Traits

Tags: tfs, xunit

I'm trying to filter out some unit test marked with the xunit trait category. On my build server I don't want unit test to run with category *integration*

```
 [Trait("Category", "Integration")]
```

When I don't use the 'Test Filter criteria' in TFS VS test step, the unit test all get executed. But when I apply the desired filter

```
Category!=Integration
```

It doesn't run any tests at all. I've tried all variations but no success. I also tried using the 2.* version of the test task.

Comment: Are you using vNext  build definition or XAML build definition?

Comment: I'm using TFS 2017 native build definition. Definitely not XAML

Comment: Test Filter Criteria in vsts-tasks, this option works the same way as the console option `/TestCaseFilter` of vstest.console.exe. To narrow down if the issue related to TFS build definition. Suggest you try to manually run  the test in the local use vstest.console.exe and `/TestCaseFilter` to see if it works.

Comment: Try to add the Test Category using this method : `[TestCategory("Integration")]`.  Then in VS Test step, set : `TestCategory!=Integration`

Comment: It seems that this is bug between xUnit a TFS: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5f85cb7-e003-4207-a8f0-31a2bfd09e9a/testcategory-attributes-of-xunit-tests-do-not-end-up-in-trx-file-on-tfs-20152?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: Tried this today and it worked for me, only 'dumb' thing is that VSTS doesn't report those tests as skipped, so skipped count was 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now (Februaray 2022), this is not problem anymore. However, I have had some issues getting it working and I have ended up here anyway, so just couple of points:

- Must be in such configuration built where the test project is really built (e.g. in Release the test project is often not built)
- Multiple detected test dlls seem to cause trouble (better to filter just really those you want)
- The name of the trait (and the value ) can be arbitrary (16.8 and 17.0.0 at least), i.e. the text in Test Filter Criteria does NOT need anymore to be some of the vstest standard names, like TestCategory

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [Trait("Category", "Integration")], use [Trait("TestCategory", "Integration")].  XUnit doesn't care what you put in for these key-value pairs, but the TFS Test runner task DOES.  The Test Filter Criteria box only works with a prescribed set of attributes.  I have this working for our builds.  Ran into the same problem you are describing.  After analyzing the build output, (and getting ALL test projects switched to XUnit - that is also a key... don't have a mix of MSTest and XUnit).